# How do i make the right side of web page scrollable, while the left side fixed

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

i am working on a blog where i want the blog posts on the left, the admin on the right, in essence a full blog (user/developer) interfaces on one page, but i want the developer side to be scrollable and the user interface to be fixed.

take a look at the css;

```
.h-100-vh {
    height: 100vh !important;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

.scroll-y {
    overflow-y: auto !important;
    overflow-x: hidden !important;
}

.rounded-xxlg-top {
    border-top-left-radius: 14px;
    border-top-right-radius: 14px;
}

.rounded-xxlg-bottom {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 14px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 14px;
}

.nav-tabs .nav-link.active {
    color: white !important;
    background-color: #007bff !important;
}
```

some of the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Wicked Blog</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap-4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/custom.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container-fluid" style="position: sticky;">
        <div class="row mt-3">
            <div class="col-md-8 blog-left">
                <div class="shadow-sm">
                    <div class="header py-3 bg-primary text-center rounded-xxlg">
                        <img src="assets/media/images/brand/logo/logoBW.png" width="140" alt="" class="img-fluid">
                        <h1 class="text-white mt-3">Welcome to <span>Wicked Blog</span></h1>
                    </div>
                    <main class="py-5">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit cumque sint debitis quaerat explicabo optio in ipsa aliquid? Quaerat culpa suscipit impedit libero obcaecati ex. Nulla sed, quis amet ex quas itaque quo, facilis voluptatem quaerat nobis omnis autem ducimus doloribus corrupti voluptas minima illum suscipit sit perspiciatis ut placeat earum, ab ullam et? Veniam deserunt exercitationem porro impedit quisquam aspernatur, ducimus quos ipsum quibusdam ad quidem temporibus velit eveniet magni officiis, voluptate incidunt ex, eligendi sequi quae facere eaque neque quia commodi. Dolorum consequatur est harum possimus quis beatae repellat quibusdam laborum sed nesciunt facere voluptatem officia quas exercitationem, necessitatibus atque eos, nulla dolores sint. Nobis iste magni cupiditate fugit consequatur aliquid rerum atque debitis cumque exercitationem inventore non at ducimus rem, beatae nostrum minus, voluptatem ipsa? Molestiae, non. Debitis, quis.</p><br>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit cumque sint debitis quaerat explicabo optio in ipsa aliquid? Quaerat culpa suscipit impedit libero obcaecati ex. Nulla sed, quis amet ex quas itaque quo, facilis voluptatem quaerat nobis omnis autem ducimus doloribus corrupti voluptas minima illum suscipit sit perspiciatis ut placeat earum, ab ullam et? Veniam deserunt exercitationem porro impedit quisquam aspernatur, ducimus quos ipsum quibusdam ad quidem temporibus velit eveniet magni officiis, voluptate incidunt ex, eligendi sequi quae facere eaque neque quia commodi. Dolorum consequatur est harum possimus quis beatae repellat quibusdam laborum sed nesciunt facere voluptatem officia quas exercitationem, necessitatibus atque eos, nulla dolores sint. Nobis iste magni cupiditate fugit consequatur aliquid rerum atque debitis cumque exercitationem inventore non at ducimus rem, beatae nostrum minus, voluptatem ipsa? Molestiae, non. Debitis, quis.</p><br><br>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit cumque sint debitis quaerat explicabo optio in ipsa aliquid? Quaerat culpa suscipit impedit libero obcaecati ex. Nulla sed, quis amet ex quas itaque quo, facilis voluptatem quaerat nobis omnis autem ducimus doloribus corrupti voluptas minima illum suscipit sit perspiciatis ut placeat earum, ab ullam et? Veniam deserunt exercitationem porro impedit quisquam aspernatur, ducimus quos ipsum quibusdam ad quidem temporibus velit eveniet magni officiis, voluptate incidunt ex, eligendi sequi quae facere eaque neque quia commodi. Dolorum consequatur est harum possimus quis beatae repellat quibusdam laborum sed nesciunt facere voluptatem officia quas exercitationem, necessitatibus atque eos, nulla dolores sint. Nobis iste magni cupiditate fugit consequatur aliquid rerum atque debitis cumque exercitationem inventore non at ducimus rem, beatae nostrum minus, voluptatem ipsa? Molestiae, non. Debitis, quis.</p>
                    </main>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 blog-right shadow-lg">

                <!-- Tab panes -->
                <div class="tab-content px-3 py-4">
                    <?php if(isset($_GET['avw']) && $_GET['avw'] == 'new-blog'): ?>
                    <div class="tab-pane active">
                        <form action="" method="post">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Title</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Title">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Content</label>
                                <textarea name="content" class="form-control" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group form-check">
                                <label>Category</label>
                                <select name="category" id="category" class="form-control form-select">
                                    <option value="">--Pick Category--</option>
                                    <option value="">option</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="">Cover Image</label>
                                <input type="file" name="coverImage" class="form-control form-control-file">
                            </div>
                            <div class="preview-box p-5 m-5 bg-dark">

                            </div>
                            <div class="text-center">
                                <button type="submit" name="saveBlog" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
                                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <?php endif ?>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

i tried to give the whole page a height and use the overflow-y property, i also tried the position:fixed prop, but no change, the whole page is still scrollable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you probably want:

```css
.my-container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
.my-container > div {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-container">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    Left column content here...
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    Right column content here...
  </div>
</div>
```

See it working:

```css
.split-screen {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.split-screen>div {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<link
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  rel="stylesheet"
/>
<div class="split-screen">
  <div class="left-panel container-fluid">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus sed erat
      vel mauris pellentesque faucibus vel et purus. Nam convallis metus justo,
      at efficitur sapien lacinia varius. Sed pulvinar turpis ut lorem dapibus
      venenatis. Vestibulum laoreet mattis efficitur. Aliquam lobortis augue
      venenatis eleifend gravida. Etiam quis felis luctus, facilisis metus in,
      interdum diam. Aenean in ullamcorper orci. Ut sed elit feugiat, accumsan
      lectus eu, euismod nisl. Fusce finibus, libero quis tempor sollicitudin,
      dui leo convallis nunc, nec efficitur mi purus at augue. Maecenas volutpat
      ornare tincidunt. Aliquam erat volutpat. Vivamus tristique sem vitae est
      euismod, sed ultrices tortor cursus.
    </p>

    <p>
      Maecenas aliquet volutpat hendrerit. Sed eget justo non odio finibus
      cursus sit amet id augue. Ut rutrum vitae metus et suscipit. Morbi porta
      porta vestibulum. Sed id sem posuere, feugiat sapien vitae, tempor est. In
      tincidunt tortor nec euismod laoreet. Duis eget ultrices lacus. Vivamus
      dictum eget diam sit amet congue. Quisque placerat, ligula sed dapibus
      sagittis, arcu sem tincidunt ligula, ac fringilla elit leo vitae lacus.
      Duis consectetur elementum pharetra. Aenean eget commodo urna.
    </p>

    <p>
      Proin commodo lacus justo, ac bibendum mi congue nec. Sed fermentum
      suscipit diam, quis porta nibh sagittis in. Integer nisi lacus, efficitur
      eget ullamcorper id, ornare a felis. Phasellus gravida tellus tortor, eget
      tempor eros blandit et. Suspendisse vel eros sit amet augue eleifend
      ullamcorper sed eget felis. Quisque vitae semper libero. Nunc consectetur
      euismod rhoncus. Curabitur tristique ultricies mollis. Aenean vel pharetra
      purus. Nam interdum felis a arcu convallis, at lobortis mi vehicula.
      Aenean a ullamcorper lacus.
    </p>

    <p>
      Proin ullamcorper lorem semper, mollis velit vitae, accumsan nunc.
      Vestibulum eget lorem in lacus vulputate lacinia. Etiam malesuada a augue
      sed aliquet. Integer vitae aliquet odio. Ut pharetra ut nisl condimentum
      sodales. Pellentesque a elit tellus. Nam fringilla lacus quis turpis
      varius, ac cursus nibh interdum. Nam interdum pellentesque dolor vitae
      sollicitudin.
    </p>

    <p>
      Proin nisi tellus, tincidunt maximus accumsan a, consequat at dui. Morbi
      mattis pretium nibh, sed finibus dui laoreet a. Mauris tempor ullamcorper
      nisl. Donec ligula odio, lacinia ut pellentesque ultricies, hendrerit nec
      lectus. Donec dolor enim, pharetra vel elit nec, tempor dignissim quam.
      Nulla facilisi. Pellentesque ultrices elementum erat, at rhoncus est
      venenatis ac. Aenean a risus ac lorem egestas fringilla in in sapien.
      Nullam id iaculis magna. Mauris nunc enim, sollicitudin ut sagittis vitae,
      euismod at neque. Phasellus tincidunt nec risus vitae dapibus. Suspendisse
      id ipsum non urna fringilla iaculis. Nam convallis erat vitae augue
      aliquet volutpat. Quisque consequat nisl non velit dapibus, sit amet porta
      enim rhoncus. Vivamus ipsum risus, fermentum vel arcu vel, luctus feugiat
      ante.
    </p>

    <p>
      Etiam elementum a enim eget pharetra. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in
      faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Fusce porta
      molestie augue, at posuere mi vestibulum eu. Suspendisse quis libero nisl.
      Morbi congue odio ut urna porta, quis molestie libero condimentum.
      Pellentesque dolor tortor, iaculis vitae eleifend cursus, fermentum ac
      purus. Suspendisse gravida dictum erat eu viverra.
    </p>

    <p>
      Cras elit odio, fermentum et ornare nec, viverra ut augue. In ac lobortis
      ex, a tincidunt est. Phasellus justo nunc, ornare vel accumsan at, rhoncus
      sed justo. Quisque at euismod orci, facilisis porta purus. Suspendisse
      suscipit eleifend nisl, sed semper libero faucibus ut. Suspendisse
      potenti. Nunc condimentum viverra ante, vel fermentum dolor fermentum a.
      Etiam hendrerit tellus quis faucibus porta. Aliquam aliquam, diam ut
      cursus volutpat, dolor libero ultrices quam, nec consectetur lacus est a
      ex. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes,
      nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam aliquet tempus felis, a pellentesque
      sapien ullamcorper sit amet.
    </p>

    <p>
      Morbi porta, est nec sollicitudin mattis, risus lorem malesuada nulla, eu
      fringilla ipsum sem eu augue. Sed at enim porta, tincidunt tortor vitae,
      feugiat ipsum. Nulla sed arcu sit amet turpis suscipit posuere.
      Pellentesque tempor libero vulputate viverra tincidunt. Nam id mi vitae
      metus lacinia efficitur nec at erat. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in
      faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Sed in diam
      porttitor, consectetur risus quis, posuere mauris. Morbi tincidunt auctor
      urna, at fermentum ante laoreet non. Sed eget turpis at mi malesuada
      vehicula ac et dui. Etiam neque odio, volutpat nec eros sed, tempor congue
      nisl. Sed ut erat non orci fringilla varius at non nisl. Nunc commodo
      fringilla eros, eget sodales tortor vestibulum eu. Integer tellus sapien,
      porttitor ut suscipit eget, cursus et justo. Suspendisse tortor ante,
      lacinia sit amet velit ac, dapibus iaculis urna. Suspendisse feugiat,
      magna nec volutpat sollicitudin, ante enim molestie nisi, a ornare ligula
      ipsum ultrices magna. Praesent dictum varius risus.
    </p>

    <p>
      Nulla facilisi. Praesent sagittis, elit ac commodo viverra, ex augue porta
      libero, nec varius ex turpis a neque. In sit amet convallis tortor, eget
      efficitur tortor. Vivamus aliquet mauris quis egestas porta. Quisque
      viverra ultricies nibh, non rhoncus purus placerat at. Maecenas aliquam
      est nec nulla dapibus vestibulum. Aliquam semper ante quis justo
      condimentum, sit amet blandit libero bibendum. In egestas ligula sapien.
      In rutrum rhoncus maximus.
    </p>

    <p>
      Morbi in vulputate felis. Sed sed interdum est. Cras a consectetur libero,
      at aliquam mi. Aliquam in eros urna. Ut scelerisque, lacus quis tempor
      rutrum, nisi diam finibus massa, eu bibendum lectus magna id purus. Proin
      elementum nisi odio, quis ultrices enim consectetur ac. Morbi vel ultrices
      felis, vitae euismod ante. Fusce volutpat scelerisque urna ac tincidunt.
      In id lacus pretium, commodo purus eu, finibus enim. Vestibulum sit amet
      sodales magna, in pretium ante. Nunc maximus scelerisque sapien ut
      maximus. Fusce bibendum dignissim mattis. Mauris volutpat, nibh a mollis
      placerat, odio tellus tincidunt erat, eu volutpat nibh eros a nulla. Sed
      nec aliquam eros. Morbi condimentum, metus vel facilisis viverra, tellus
      nisl condimentum augue, a ullamcorper est ipsum eu enim.
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="right-panel container-fluid">Some other content here</div>
</div>
```

It doesn't matter how much content each column has. When its content no longer fits the height, it starts being scrollable:

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .split-screen {
    height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  }
  .split-screen>div {
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<link
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  rel="stylesheet"
/>
<div class="split-screen">
  <div class="container-fluid">Some other content here</div>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus sed erat
      vel mauris pellentesque faucibus vel et purus. Nam convallis metus justo,
      at efficitur sapien lacinia varius. Sed pulvinar turpis ut lorem dapibus
      venenatis. Vestibulum laoreet mattis efficitur. Aliquam lobortis augue
      venenatis eleifend gravida. Etiam quis felis luctus, facilisis metus in,
      interdum diam. Aenean in ullamcorper orci. Ut sed elit feugiat, accumsan
      lectus eu, euismod nisl. Fusce finibus, libero quis tempor sollicitudin,
      dui leo convallis nunc, nec efficitur mi purus at augue. Maecenas volutpat
      ornare tincidunt. Aliquam erat volutpat. Vivamus tristique sem vitae est
      euismod, sed ultrices tortor cursus.
    </p>

    <p>
      Maecenas aliquet volutpat hendrerit. Sed eget justo non odio finibus
      cursus sit amet id augue. Ut rutrum vitae metus et suscipit. Morbi porta
      porta vestibulum. Sed id sem posuere, feugiat sapien vitae, tempor est. In
      tincidunt tortor nec euismod laoreet. Duis eget ultrices lacus. Vivamus
      dictum eget diam sit amet congue. Quisque placerat, ligula sed dapibus
      sagittis, arcu sem tincidunt ligula, ac fringilla elit leo vitae lacus.
      Duis consectetur elementum pharetra. Aenean eget commodo urna.
    </p>

    <p>
      Proin commodo lacus justo, ac bibendum mi congue nec. Sed fermentum
      suscipit diam, quis porta nibh sagittis in. Integer nisi lacus, efficitur
      eget ullamcorper id, ornare a felis. Phasellus gravida tellus tortor, eget
      tempor eros blandit et. Suspendisse vel eros sit amet augue eleifend
      ullamcorper sed eget felis. Quisque vitae semper libero. Nunc consectetur
      euismod rhoncus. Curabitur tristique ultricies mollis. Aenean vel pharetra
      purus. Nam interdum felis a arcu convallis, at lobortis mi vehicula.
      Aenean a ullamcorper lacus.
    </p>

    <p>
      Proin ullamcorper lorem semper, mollis velit vitae, accumsan nunc.
      Vestibulum eget lorem in lacus vulputate lacinia. Etiam malesuada a augue
      sed aliquet. Integer vitae aliquet odio. Ut pharetra ut nisl condimentum
      sodales. Pellentesque a elit tellus. Nam fringilla lacus quis turpis
      varius, ac cursus nibh interdum. Nam interdum pellentesque dolor vitae
      sollicitudin.
    </p>

    <p>
      Proin nisi tellus, tincidunt maximus accumsan a, consequat at dui. Morbi
      mattis pretium nibh, sed finibus dui laoreet a. Mauris tempor ullamcorper
      nisl. Donec ligula odio, lacinia ut pellentesque ultricies, hendrerit nec
      lectus. Donec dolor enim, pharetra vel elit nec, tempor dignissim quam.
      Nulla facilisi. Pellentesque ultrices elementum erat, at rhoncus est
      venenatis ac. Aenean a risus ac lorem egestas fringilla in in sapien.
      Nullam id iaculis magna. Mauris nunc enim, sollicitudin ut sagittis vitae,
      euismod at neque. Phasellus tincidunt nec risus vitae dapibus. Suspendisse
      id ipsum non urna fringilla iaculis. Nam convallis erat vitae augue
      aliquet volutpat. Quisque consequat nisl non velit dapibus, sit amet porta
      enim rhoncus. Vivamus ipsum risus, fermentum vel arcu vel, luctus feugiat
      ante.
    </p>

    <p>
      Etiam elementum a enim eget pharetra. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in
      faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Fusce porta
      molestie augue, at posuere mi vestibulum eu. Suspendisse quis libero nisl.
      Morbi congue odio ut urna porta, quis molestie libero condimentum.
      Pellentesque dolor tortor, iaculis vitae eleifend cursus, fermentum ac
      purus. Suspendisse gravida dictum erat eu viverra.
    </p>

    <p>
      Cras elit odio, fermentum et ornare nec, viverra ut augue. In ac lobortis
      ex, a tincidunt est. Phasellus justo nunc, ornare vel accumsan at, rhoncus
      sed justo. Quisque at euismod orci, facilisis porta purus. Suspendisse
      suscipit eleifend nisl, sed semper libero faucibus ut. Suspendisse
      potenti. Nunc condimentum viverra ante, vel fermentum dolor fermentum a.
      Etiam hendrerit tellus quis faucibus porta. Aliquam aliquam, diam ut
      cursus volutpat, dolor libero ultrices quam, nec consectetur lacus est a
      ex. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes,
      nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam aliquet tempus felis, a pellentesque
      sapien ullamcorper sit amet.
    </p>

    <p>
      Morbi porta, est nec sollicitudin mattis, risus lorem malesuada nulla, eu
      fringilla ipsum sem eu augue. Sed at enim porta, tincidunt tortor vitae,
      feugiat ipsum. Nulla sed arcu sit amet turpis suscipit posuere.
      Pellentesque tempor libero vulputate viverra tincidunt. Nam id mi vitae
      metus lacinia efficitur nec at erat. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in
      faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Sed in diam
      porttitor, consectetur risus quis, posuere mauris. Morbi tincidunt auctor
      urna, at fermentum ante laoreet non. Sed eget turpis at mi malesuada
      vehicula ac et dui. Etiam neque odio, volutpat nec eros sed, tempor congue
      nisl. Sed ut erat non orci fringilla varius at non nisl. Nunc commodo
      fringilla eros, eget sodales tortor vestibulum eu. Integer tellus sapien,
      porttitor ut suscipit eget, cursus et justo. Suspendisse tortor ante,
      lacinia sit amet velit ac, dapibus iaculis urna. Suspendisse feugiat,
      magna nec volutpat sollicitudin, ante enim molestie nisi, a ornare ligula
      ipsum ultrices magna. Praesent dictum varius risus.
    </p>

    <p>
      Nulla facilisi. Praesent sagittis, elit ac commodo viverra, ex augue porta
      libero, nec varius ex turpis a neque. In sit amet convallis tortor, eget
      efficitur tortor. Vivamus aliquet mauris quis egestas porta. Quisque
      viverra ultricies nibh, non rhoncus purus placerat at. Maecenas aliquam
      est nec nulla dapibus vestibulum. Aliquam semper ante quis justo
      condimentum, sit amet blandit libero bibendum. In egestas ligula sapien.
      In rutrum rhoncus maximus.
    </p>

    <p>
      Morbi in vulputate felis. Sed sed interdum est. Cras a consectetur libero,
      at aliquam mi. Aliquam in eros urna. Ut scelerisque, lacus quis tempor
      rutrum, nisi diam finibus massa, eu bibendum lectus magna id purus. Proin
      elementum nisi odio, quis ultrices enim consectetur ac. Morbi vel ultrices
      felis, vitae euismod ante. Fusce volutpat scelerisque urna ac tincidunt.
      In id lacus pretium, commodo purus eu, finibus enim. Vestibulum sit amet
      sodales magna, in pretium ante. Nunc maximus scelerisque sapien ut
      maximus. Fusce bibendum dignissim mattis. Mauris volutpat, nibh a mollis
      placerat, odio tellus tincidunt erat, eu volutpat nibh eros a nulla. Sed
      nec aliquam eros. Morbi condimentum, metus vel facilisis viverra, tellus
      nisl condimentum augue, a ullamcorper est ipsum eu enim.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Most importantly, you probably want to wrap the entire CSS above in a

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) { 
  /* content here... */
}
```

... so this split screen only happens on `md` and above (like in the second example).

Comment: I applied your suggestion to my code and the .my-container class I used to wrap the entire document, now my screen Is split into 3 different parts and not working as it should, I appreciate the effort but I'm still stuck

Comment: Consider creating a *runnable* [mcve] with what you currently have. Nobody could help you if you don't show more context as we have no way of knowing how the rest of your markup/layout looks like.

Comment: i just did that now, please take a look at the problem again and see if you can help me out

Comment: It looks like you have a different definition for *"runnable"*. Copy/paste the markup (HTML code) of your page into jsfiddle or codesandbox. Not the source code, because you don't have php in a sandbox. The resulting HTML of the page (you can get it by right-clicking the page -> View Page Source).

Comment: [This is](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/5g2rnby3/) what *runnable* means. As you can see, the proposed solution works. Also, the snippets in my answer are runnable (they have a "Run" button and you can see the outcome).